# Get intersection element in BabylonJS

Tags: intersection, babylonjs

Is there a way to get the actual intersection of to geometries with BabylonJS?

E.g. the intersection point of a line and a plane, the line intersection of two planes, the arc intersection of a sphere and a plane, etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you are looking for is the CSG (Constructive Solid Geometry) tools in Babylon.js. To use it you can reference this tutorial [here](https://github.com/CraigFeldspar/BabylonCSG). 
Essentially what you want to do is the following:

### CSG intersect  (modified code from the link)

```
// a and b can be any mesh you define
var a = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateBox("box", 500, scene); 
var b = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateBox("box", 500, scene);

// Convert to CSG meshes
var aCSG = BABYLON.CSG.FromMesh(a);
var bCSG = BABYLON.CSG.FromMesh(b);
var subCSG = bCSG.intersect(aCSG);

// Disposing original meshes since we don't want to see them on the scene
a.dispose();
b.dispose();

// Convert back to regular mesh from CSG mesh
subCSG.toMesh("csg", new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("mat", scene), scene);
```

For more uses of CSG you should check out the [documentation](https://doc.babylonjs.com/classes/2.5/csg).

Comment: I see a  weird problem here: the resulting mesh always has position (0,0,0), wherever it appears in the scene!  https://playground.babylonjs.com/#RN1JE7#1